# Is there a way of creating a bigquery function that returns the last access date for a given table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I can give a table id in the format project.dataset.table (e.g: b2bproject.sales.daily_agg)

What I want is an UDF to return the last access date of it.

I expect to use this way:

```
SELECT *, GET_LAST_ACCESS(my_table) FROM myListOfTables
```

Is that possible within BQ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no query result for last read inside BQ,The closest I can get is create table date from this query `SELECT * from <projectId>.<datasetID>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name = "<tableName>"`

Reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro).

And alternative is querying in Google Logging:

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
protoPayload.authorizationInfo.resource="projects/<proj_ID>/datasets/<datasetName>/tables/<tableName>"
protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.insert"
```